# .next() jumps two steps instead of one, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I'm making a web-based quiz. 
When I press an answer I want the count at the top to change to the next, however it keeps skipping one digit, jumping to the next (e.i. from I to III, instead of I to III).
What am I doing wrong?

Site: http://www.carlpapworth.com/friday-quiz/#

Html:

```
<ul id="count">
                <li><h4>I</h4></li>
                <li><h4>II</h4></li>
                <li><h4>III</h4></li>
                <li><h4>IV</h4></li>
                <li><h4>V</h4></li>
                <li><h4>VI</h4></li>
                <li><h4>VII</h4></li>
                <li><h4>VIII</h4></li>
                <li><h4>IX</h4></li>
                <li><h4>X</h4></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
  $('#count li:first').addClass('cCurrent');
        $('.qAnswers li a').click(qNext);
        function qNext(){
          $('.cCurrent').next('#count li').addClass('cCurrent');
          $('.cCurrent:first').removeClass('cCurrent'); 
        }
```

Comment: The code works just fine when I test it: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/dxuqb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in your javascript, but your HTML page includes the same script twice. If the click event is registered twice, it probably causes your issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/custom.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src='js/custom.js'></script>
```

Comment: Thx, this was definetly the main problem.

Answer (score 4):

The `js/custom.js` script is mentioned **twice** in the `<head>`. You should remove one of them, otherwise the click events are registered twice.

Furthermore, the expression inside `.next()` looks somewhat odd (you don't need the `#count` in there and maybe not even `li`) and the function itself can be simplified to this:

```
function qNext()
{
    $('#count .cCurrent')
        .removeClass('cCurrent')
        .next('li')
        .addClass('cCurrent');
}
```

It removes the class of the currently highlighted `<li>`, then moves to the next `<li>` and applies the `cCurrent` class there.

Lastly, you shouldn't give your answers a class that gives away that the answer is correct or wrong. Your answers had something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="qWrong">xxx</a>
<a href="#" class="qCorrect">xxx</a>
```

If someone would look at the source, it would be very obvious what to click.

Comment: Well, this makes a lot cleaner code, thanks for that, as pointed out the double js/custom.js load was what was causing the problem :)
♥ u guys!

Comment: @CarlPapworth Don't forget to remove the revealing class names you've used on the answer links.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with jquery specifics, but I would debug this with adding some trace, inna spirit of:

```
function qNext(){
    // Output data on what is your current question
    $('.cCurrent').next('#count li').addClass('cCurrent');
    // Output something - so you know for sure that this is the line that does the double move
    $('.cCurrent:first').removeClass('cCurrent'); 
}
```

And you can also try:

```
function qNext(){
    // Output ...
    $myObject = $('.cCurrent');
    // Output ...
    $myObject2 = $myObject.next('#count li');
    // Output ...
    $myObject2.addClass('cCurrent');
    // Output ...
    $('.cCurrent:first').removeClass('cCurrent'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the qnext function is working correctly

I assume the Problem is that theres also another click event, which does also slide one Question to the right, added to the answers by the slider (ulslide). Try to comment out this line and see if it works

```
nextButton: '.qAnswers a',
```